# Filtering Objects in Database by Keyword

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.8.3 and Python 3.4.3

I will try to explain this so it makes sense, so please bear with me.  I've imported a csv file into my database with roughly 50 rows and 10 columns of data, which consists of data pulled from Google Analytics and our email marketing campaign data.  One of the columns is 'day_of_week'.  I need to get a count of the database rows that have the keyword of the day I need...the only way I can figure out how to do it is with the code below, but man, it sure seems it could be more dynamic and cleaner.

Is there a way to filter it in a way I can use a tag in the template, or something cleaner than this?  Thank you for your help.

```
class EmailListView(ListView):
    model = Email
    template_name = 'dashboard/pages/email.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmailListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
        months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
                  'November', 'December']
        subject_type = ['Offer', 'Sell', 'Fear', 'Learn']
        content_type = ['Offer', 'Sell', 'Fear', 'Learn']
        email_list = ['FMG - Business', 'FMG - Residential', 'AE', 'IBA']

        total_campaigns_monday = {}
        total_campaigns_tuesday = {},
        total_campaigns_wednesday = {},
        total_campaigns_thursday = {},
        total_campaigns_friday = {},
        total_campaigns_saturday = {},
        total_campaigns_sunday = {},
        total_recipients = {}
        total_unsubscribes = {}
        total_bounces = {}
        total_open = {}
        total_clicks = {}

        for campaigns in days:
            total_campaigns_monday = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week='Monday').count()
            total_campaigns_monday = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week='Tuesday').count()
            total_campaigns_monday = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week='Wednesday').count()
            total_campaigns_monday = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week='Thursday').count()
            total_campaigns_monday = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week='Friday').count()
            total_campaigns_monday = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week='Saturday').count()
            total_campaigns_monday = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week='Sunday').count()
```

And a snippet of my template ( notice the first  is different than the others.)

```
{% if email_list %}
<tr>
   <td>Monday</td>
   <td>{{ total_campaigns_monday }}</td>
   <td>{{ total_recipients.Monday }}</td>
   <td>{{ total_unsubscribes.Monday  }}</td>
   <td>{{ total_bounces.Monday  }}</td>
   <td>{{ total_open.Monday  }}</td>
   <td>{{ total_clicks.Monday  }}</td>
   <td>{% average total_open.Monday total_recipients.Monday %}</td>
   <td>{% average total_clicks.Monday total_open.Monday %}</td>
   </tr>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your queston.

Replace `total_campaigns_<day_of_week>` statements and `for` loop with

```
total_campaigns = {}
for day in days:
    total_campaigns[day] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day).count()
```

In templates you can use `{{ total_campaigns.Monday }}` or `{{ total_campaigns.Sunday }}` or something similar.

Comment: Wow, that is so simple - clean and very similar to the rest of my code!!  Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one query with [aggregation methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count
days_and_counts = Email.objects.values('day_of_week').annotate(count=Count('day_of_week'), distinct=True)
```

will give you something like this in `days_and_counts` (output from my randomly populated data set):

```
[
    {'day_of_week': 'Friday', 'count': 7},
    {'day_of_week': 'Monday', 'count': 5},
    {'day_of_week': 'Saturday', 'count': 2},
    {'day_of_week': 'Sunday', 'count': 12},
    {'day_of_week': 'Thursday', 'count': 11},
    {'day_of_week': 'Tuesday', 'count': 6},
    {'day_of_week': 'Wednesday', 'count': 7}
]
```

From there, you can build a dict like f43d65 suggested:

```
total_campaigns = {x['day_of_week']: x['count'] for x in days_and_counts}
```

which will give you something like this in `total_campaigns`:

```
{
    'Wednesday': 7,
    'Thursday': 11,
    'Tuesday': 6,
    'Monday': 5,
    'Saturday': 2,
    'Sunday': 12,
    'Friday': 7
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be '.annotate(count=Count('day_of_week'), distinct=True)' ?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.  I went with f43d65's solution because it closely matched the rest of my code.  Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, for the edit. And glad to help, Studio Rooster—glad you found something that works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can be cleaner:

```
        days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

        total_campaigns = {
            day:Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day).count()
            for day in days
        }
```

I recommend checking out dictionary comprehensions